# Bootstrap 3 topnav that turns into sidebar when in small screens?

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I'm relatively experienced with Bootstrap 2, and can usually get it to do what I want, but I'm having an issue with Bootstrap 3.

I'm trying to have a top nav across the page, and a secondary top nav underneath it.  The secondary top nav, when the screen is big enough, should pop over to be a sidebar.

I'm pretty stuck, and don't know where to go from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/.

Thanks!

EDIT:  This is what I have.  It shows the idea, but the nav is defined twice.  Take a look, you'll see what I mean.  http://jsfiddle.net/xwp7S/2/

I have the sidebar defined as:

```
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>Sidebar</li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.well -->
        </div>
```

and the top nav defined as

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".topnav-collapse">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse topnav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

and extra css of

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #topsidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

How do I approach the problem of not defining the nav twice?

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far for html?